# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' Dart

Tags: wordpress, flutter, api, dart

I am making a flutter application with the Wordpress Rest-Api and at the time of the call I encounter the following problem:

```
E/flutter (11196): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

The truth is that I deduce that the problem is caused by the fact that the worpress rest-api returns a list, and the method needs a string, but I have no idea what else to do... I have been searching the internet and I only get more complicated.

```
class CategoriesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _baseUrl = 'webpage.net';
  String _fields = 'id,count,description,name,link';

  CategoriesProvider() {
    getCategories();
  }

  getCategories() async {
    var url =
        Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'wp-json/wp/v2/categories', {'_fields': _fields});

    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    final categories = CategoriesResponse.fromJson(response.body);


    print(categories.count);

  }
}
```

My model (response)

```
class CategoriesResponse {
    CategoriesResponse({
        required this.id,
        required this.count,
        required this.description,
        required this.name,
    });

    int id;
    int count;
    String description;
    String name;

    factory CategoriesResponse.fromJson(String str) => CategoriesResponse.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory CategoriesResponse.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CategoriesResponse(
        id: json["id"],
        count: json["count"],
        description: json["description"],
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "count": count,
        "description": description,
        "name": name,
    };
}
```

If someone could help me I would be very grateful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
class CategoriesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _baseUrl = 'webpage.net';
  String _fields = 'id,count,description,name,link';

  CategoriesProvider() {
    getCategories();
  }

  getCategories() async {
    var url =
        Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'wp-json/wp/v2/categories', {'_fields': _fields});

    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    
    var responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    responseJson as List;
    final categories = responseJson.map((e)=> CategoriesResponse.fromJson(e));


    print(categories.count);

  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: : Error: The getter 'count' isn't defined for the class 'Iterable<CategoriesResponse>'.
lib/providers/categories_provider.dart:27
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'CategoriesResponse' is from 'package:curso_de_informatica/models/categories_reponse.dart' ('lib/models/categories_reponse.dart').
package:curso_de_informatica/models/categories_reponse.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'count'.
    print(categories.count);

Comment: print(categories.count) instead of this print(categories.toList().length)